# Android Studio parent directory for lock file

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, locking

Could you help me with the following problem:

I'm using the new Flamingo version of Android Studio and when I go to emulate the first part of the kotlin app, with only the layout ready, I get the following message:

Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.0-bin\ca5e32bp14vu59qr306oxotwh\gradle-8.0-bin.zip.lck

Could you give some guidance on how to proceed?
Thanks

I re-installed android studio but it didn't solve.

Comment: Check that the current Windows logged-in user has a permission to modify this path.

Comment: Have you Googled or searched Stackoverflow for this error already? There are a ton of hits for the term "android Could not create parent directory for lock file".